Why I get "workflow was not found" for a shared workflow at my github enterprise repo?
One of our shared workflow/github actions is running for some of our enterprise repositories but not running for others with errors:

error parsing called workflow


workflow was not found

Why can some of our enterprise repositories not access it?

It turns out that there 3 visibility settings for repositories in github enterprise:

private
internal
public

It seems that when a repository `s visibility is set to public, it cannot use the shared workflow. Setting it to internal, solve the issue and the workflow is running.
To change the visibility, go to Settings->General->Danger Zone
and
Change visibility->internal
References

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/sharing-automations/sharing-actions-and-workflows-with-your-enterprise

